# Passing the Variable and its value from one html page to other html page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have made some calcutation using Jquery in Page1.html by getting the value from inputbox and inputbox1 using get function and store the variable Z and its value by setting in inputbox2 using set function of jquery. Now i want to pass the variable Z and its value in Page2.html. Kindly help me out.

```html
Jquery Example
Page1.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
DEDUCTION: <input type="text" id="myinput1" value="">
GROSS INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput2" value="">

<button id="click1">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#click1").click(function a(){
        
  myfunction();
        
    });

   
function myfunction() {
var x, y, z;
var x = $("#myinput").val();
var y = $("#myinput1").val();

 z = x - y;
  

 $("#myinput2").val(z);
 
  
 
}

</script>

</body>
</html>

Page2.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput3" value="">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have form tag to go to page2.html?

Comment: Use:`localStorage`

Comment: You can do it . Just create a form element in Javascript and set one attribute then just post that to the 2nd page ..

Comment: and yes.. you should use any server side language to read the received data ..

Answer (score 0):

Just changing some small thing is your myfunction function :
Adding something more at the end

- Creating a form element.
- Setting attribute
- Sending the data to second page.

  ```
  function myfunction() {
  var x, y, z;
  var x = $("#myinput").val();
  var y = $("#myinput1").val();
      z = x - y;
      $("#myinput2").val(z);

  var form = document.createElement("form"); // <-- created a form element
      form.setAttribute("yourData", z); //  <--  Here is your value
      form.setAttribute("action", "index2.php"); //  <--  Setting the path where I want to send the data
      form.submit(); //  <--  Sending the data    
  }
  ```

Now here is some code in index2.php (Where you send the data) :

```
<?php
    $redeivedData = $_POST['yourData']; //<-- Your data received 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput3" value=" <?php echo $redeivedData; ?>"> <!--I just put your data here .. -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

- Please note , I used php because we need server side language to read
  the data received.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookies` or `localStorage` for this purpose.

**Using Cookie:**

repeat these codes in both pages:

```
        function updateCookie(name, value) {
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + AddMin(5) + "; path=/";//path is neccessary 4 live this cookie in all similar address.
        };
        function deleteCoockie(name) {
            document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + (new Date(0)).toUTCString() + ";";
        };
        function readCookie(name) {
            return ((document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + " ?= ?[^=]*?([^;]*)", "g")) || [""])[0]).substr(name.length + 1);
        };

        function AddMin(m) {
            var d = new Date(); d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + m);
            return d.toUTCString();
        };
```

Now in your `myfunction`:

```
updateCookie("VarName4Transfer", "DesiredValue4Transfer");
```

and in dest page:

```
var TransferedVariable2ThisPage = readCookie("VarName4Transfer");
deleteCoockie("VarName4Transfer");
```